Movie about band reunion
I saw this movie years ago possibly in the 80s and was set in the 80. It was a US film.
A couple promoters are trying reunite a popular band for a concert. The problem is they lose track of the lead singer.  
The lead singer is a single dad who works at a gas station. At one point he washes the windows of the promoters car without them realizing who he is.
There is a second storyline about the son wanting to be a musician. He tries our for a school concert but gets rejected again. (First time had because of the length if the members hair second because of their music). 
The kid accuses the faculty of not liking rock music and the faculty mentions the Carpenters being performed the previous year.
The kid later tries out at the promoters event and reveals who he is. He takes them to his father and they are shocked to see they had been there.

We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
